# Using `std::call_once` for lazy initialization

Tags: c++, concurrency, lazy-initialization

Briefly, I have a class that [lazily initializes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) one of its data members and I'd like to figure out the best way to do this in a multithreaded environment.

In more detail, my class currently looks something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>

class A_single_threaded
{
public:
   bool query(const int val) const
   {
      // if opt_vec is not initialized, do that now
      if (!(opt_vec.has_value()))
         initialize_vec();

      // return true if opt_vec contains val
      return std::find(std::cbegin(opt_vec), std::cend(opt_vec), val) != std::cend(opt_vec);
   }
private:
   mutable std::optional<std::vector<int>> opt_vec;

   // sets opt_vec
   void initialize_vec() const;
};
```

`initialize_vec` is the only method that modifies `opt_vec`, and `query` is the only method that calls `initialize_vec`. `opt_vec` can potentially be empty after `initialize_vec` returns, so giving the data member `std::optional` type helps distinguish when it's unset and when it's set and empty.  In other instances `opt_vec` winds up being large and initializing it is time-consuming.  And since not every `A_single_threaded` instance will need to run `query` anyway, it makes sense to avoid initializing `opt_vec` until a user call to `query` makes clear that initialization is necessary.

The approach above seems OK for a single thread, but I think it isn't naturally multithread-able.  The calls to `opt_vec.has_value()` and `initialize_vec` are necessarily unsynchronized, and the gap between their return times allows for a data race that I don't think can be fixed with a `mutex`.  Instead I think the correct solution involves replacing the `std::optional` with `std::call_once`, something like the below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

class A_multi_threaded
{
public:
   bool query(const int val) const
   {
      // if opt_vec is not initialized, do that now
      std::call_once(opt_vec_flag, initialize_vec, this);

      // return true if opt_vec contains val
      return std::find(std::cbegin(opt_vec), std::cend(opt_vec), val) != std::cend(opt_vec);
   }
private:
   mutable std::vector<int> opt_vec;
   mutable std::once_flag opt_vec_flag;

   // sets opt_vec
   void initialize_vec() const;
};
```

I'd appreciate answers to a couple of questions:

1. Is the implementation I sketched for `A_multi_threaded` actually thread-safe?
2. Will `A_multi_threaded` have the same behavior as `A_single_threaded` in a single-threaded environment?
3. Is there a sensible implementation of `A_multi_threaded` that mimics the implementation of `A_single_threaded`?

Comment: FYI: [std::call_once](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) I had most doubts whether all threads will see the correct initialized `opt_vec`. (As long as no thread is writing no sync. is needed but the initialization is the (exceptional) writing. So...) However, I found (in this link) _this means that all concurrent calls to call_once are guaranteed to observe **any side-effects** made by the active call, **with no additional synchronization**._ (Emphasize mine.) IMHO, this describes that my doubts are wrong.

Comment: `std::call_once(opt_vec_flag, initialize_vec);` needs to be `std::call_once(opt_vec_flag, initialize_vec, this);` and using the flag like this will make the class non-movable. Aside from that I don't see any issue as far as the shown code goes. You also potentially need to make sure that destruction of `A_multi_threaded` is synchronized, e.g. by using a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: And `opt_vec_flag` also needs to be `mutable` (so I am not sure whether it really makes sense to have the functions be `const`).

Comment: Maybe using a local static initializer ?

Comment: @TerryWu That would be a simpler approach if `A_multi_threaded` is supposed to be a singleton, but doesn't work if there are supposed to be multiple `A_multi_threaded` instances.

Comment: @user17732522 Maybe using a thread_local static ?

Comment: @TerryWu Then multiple threads can't access the same vector, effectively reducing back to single-thread behavior, which I don't expect is what OP wants. Also, that still doesn't allow multiple instances in the same thread.

Comment: @user17732522 Fixed.  Good catches, thank you.